# Hausdorff dimension of sequence space

Tags: reference-request, ergodic-theory, metric-spaces, hausdorff-dimension

Let $\Omega =\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ denote the set of infinite sequences with elements $0$ or $1$. Let $d$ be the metric on $\Omega$ given by $d((x_n),(y_n))=1/2^m$, where $m=\min\{i\in\mathbb{N}\,:\,x_i\neq y_i\}$.

Define a function $\pi:\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$, where $\pi((x_n))$ is the number in $[0,1]$ with $n$th digit in its binary expansion equal to $x_n$, that is, $\pi ((x_n)) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n2^{-n}$.

Does anyone have a *reference* for published work which proves that the Hausdorff dimension of a set $X$ in the metric space $(\Omega,d)$ is equal to the Hausdorff dimension of $\pi(X)$ in $[0,1]$ with the Euclidean metric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Falconer[1] this is due to Besicovitch[2].  Falconer states it (generalized to $\mathbb R^n$) as Theorem 5.1, p. 65.  This proves more than just $X$ and $\pi(X)$ have the same Hausdorff dimension: it proves the Hausdorff measures of $X$ and $\pi(X)$ are within a constant factor of each other.

[1] K. F. Falconer, *The Geometry of Fractal Sets* (Cambridge Univ Press 1985), Chapter 5

[2] A. S. Besicovitch, *Indag. Math.* **14** (1952) 339-344

Comment: are you sure that link [2] is correct? couldn't find it on google scholar

Comment: It seems to be *Indag. Math.* not *Invent. Math* ... corrected ... Besicovitch, A. S. On existence of subsets of finite measure of sets of infinite measure. Nederl. Akad. Wetensch. Proc. Ser. A. 55 = Indagationes Math. 14, (1952). 339–344.

Comment: _Thank you_ Gerald, that was extremely useful. I now see that the material you reference can also be found, in brief, in Section 2.4 of another of Falconer's books, _Fractal Geometry_.

Answer (score 4):

This observation is attributed to H. Furstenberg, and appears (in the case of shift-invariant sets, i.e. Cantor sets) in his beautiful [Disjointness paper](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~barakw/seminar/furstenberg_disjointness.pdf) (in section $3$, which you can read independently from the previous ones, although the whole paper is magnificent).
A bit more general result appears in a subsequent paper of Furstenberg named "[Intersections of Cantor sets](https://books.google.co.il/books?hl=en&lr=&id=ZXh9BgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA41&dq=intersection%20of%20cantor%20sets&ots=dG_CShgKVz&sig=Jb70qXl_SLACRQv12j3IxyOe7X4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=intersection%20of%20cantor%20sets&f=false)"

I'm pretty sure such a result was known much before Furstenberg's (at-least to Erdos) but you wanted some specific references.

Comment: Thanks very much Amir! I'm extremely grateful for the reference - to solve my problem, and also to alert me to another outstanding paper of Furstenburg.